# Fluuter is unable to load my Asset, how do i fix it?

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-dependencies

[image]

Hi Guys,

currently i am doing my first Flutter Project with Android Studio.

And everything went good until i tried to load an image into my App, it never shows up on the Emulator.

**I tried a few steps to solve the problem.**

1. i checked my pubspec.yami folder and it seems to be ok.

assets:

- lib/images/japanflag.png

2. I did run "Flutter Clean"
3. i did run "flutter pub outdated"

And after all that it is stil not working and i made sure that my images folder is in the right place.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
      const StartPage({super.key});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255,215,165,187),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(

            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

            children: [
              Row(children: [Text("JAPAN JOURNEY",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 38,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
              ),
               Image.asset("lib/images/japanflag.png", height: 30,)

              ],
              )
```

I hope that someone can help me tho :D, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
If you added the image and you didn't stop the app,
try to stop the app and build it again, this can solve the issue.
If it does not work, try solution 2.

**Solution 2**

Create an `assets` folder inside your root project.
inside it create an `images` folder then put your `japanflag.png` image.

Inside your `pubspec.yaml` make sure to have :

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

then do `flutter pub get` in your terminal.

then display your image like:

```
Image.asset("assets/images/japanflag.png", height: 30,)
```

Stop and Build the app, the image should show up.

Comment: Hello i did everything that u said and it sadly did still not work.

Comment: Weird, contact me if you would to see it together.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the flutter way and create an assets folder for all the assets.

But in your case you should add **lib** and **lib/images** also to your assets.

From the docs:

> Only files located directly in the directory are included.
> Resolution-aware asset image variants are the only exception. To add
> files located in subdirectories, create an entry per directory.

https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your assets in the pubspec.yaml file for that scenario.

```
  assets:
     - lib/images/
```

Comment: I did try that but it did still not work. thanks for the answer